# In Java 8, how do I apply this filter?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

First of all I apologize for the title of the question, I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it, please let me know if I should fix it.

Basically I'm a Java programmer that is way too used with imperative programming, discovering (and playing with) the new features from Java 8.

The method I am writing is quite simple, and I have it working fine, I'm just wondering if there's a more "functional" way of solving this.

Basically I receive a list of `User`, and need to return the percentage of those users that have `Status = INVALID`.

So here's what I did so far:

```
public static double getFailedPercentage(List<User> users){
    Long failedCount = users.stream().filter(user -> User.Status.INVALID.equals(user.getStatus())).collect(counting());
    return (failedCount * 100) / users.size();
}
```

I would like to keep this as a *one liner* if possible, I know this might be overthinking things, but I like to know the limits and the possibilities of the language I use.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You can simply get rid of the local variable `failedCount` then you have a one-liner. But I suppose you want to have a stream that returns the percentage directly, right?

Comment: It's already a 1 liner, you just decided to make it a 2 liner to be more descriptive. Which is a good thing.

Comment: @Thilo yes, I am happy with the solution, I just want to see how far I can take it. For academic purposes

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html explains how you can use collect to do things like that.

Comment: Not to answer your question, but as you are looking out "possibilities of the language", your first line could be re-written as : `long failedCount = users.stream().map(User::getStatus).filter(User.Status.INVALID::equals).count();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work

```
return users.stream()
            .mapToInt(user -> User.Status.INVALID.equals(user.getStatus()) ? 100 : 0)
            .average()
            .getAsDouble();
```

It maps the `Status` to either 0 or 100 and then takes the average. Which means for every `INVALID` user you have a 100, for every other you have a 0, the average of that is the exact result as you requested.

The `100` is the same hundred you multiplied by. If you want a decimal representation of the percentage, replace it with a `1`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/

Comment: I like that solution, I didn't think of mapping the status to a number, that's pretty cool. Thanks! Is this a normal approach in functional programming?

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki In particular if you want to aggregate I would say yes. Because aggregate functions generally operate on numbers and therefore you only have to find a suitable mapping for your use case.